# How to the display evaluation metrics and confusion matrix for my model

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

am working on fake news detection. i have really gone fall. i have been able to display the accuracy score but i want include other evaluation metrics (Precision_score, F1_score, recall_score

this is a model for predicting fake news using features from the dataset  after scaling

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Ylabels, test_size = 0.2, random_state =42)
 logit = LogisticRegression()
 logit.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Accuracy Score: ", logit.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Accuracy Score:  0.9267158873393492
Precision Score:  0.xxxxxxx
Recall Score:  0.xxxxxxxx
F1 Score:  0.xxxxxxxxx

confusion matrix
[[xxxx     xxxxxx]
 [  xx     xxxxxx]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get a Series of your predictions

```
 preds = logit.predict(X_test)
```

Then import and call any scoring function on them

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
f1_score(y_test, preds)
```

You can see a list of a lot of the scoring functions you can use here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics